# How to create new line with css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

For example, if I have n images, and I want to arrange every 4 images in a row, is there any way to do that in CSS or js? Because the images are dynamically uploaded with AJAX, I think I need a dynamical way.

Comment: Are the images fixed-width? Can you simply inject a `<br>` after each 4th image via JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more sophisicated answer using CSS3

HTML

```
<div class="image_row">
    <img class="image_item" src="http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg" />
    <img class="image_item" src="http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg" />
    <img class="image_item" src="http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg" />
    <img class="image_item" src="http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Style
    .image_row
    {
        width:400px;
    }

```
.image_item
{
    max-width : calc(100% / 4 );
    max-width : -moz-calc(100% / 4 );
    max-width : -webkit-calc(100% / 4 );
    float:left;
}
```

Solves your dynamic width/height, and puts all 4 images into a row.

http://jsfiddle.net/gAWyU/

Edit:
As requested, added the mozilla and standard codes in.

**Update**
Just a little update to this answer. The amazing thing about the css3 `calc` function is that your container div can be of any size. I've used 400px in this example, but if you want to make it fluid, using my solution, it works too.

This is because, in my solution, the width of the image will always be 1/4 of the width of the parent div.

If you're afraid that your images will be too in width, what you could potentially do instead is set a fixed minimum width, and set the max-width to match the parent div. Here's a working example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAWyU/4/)

Note that you'll only need to set a minimum width for the parent div; as the images will ALWAYS be 1/4 of the width of your parent div.

Here's the CSS:

```
.image_row
{
    width:100%;
    min-width:400px;
}

.image_item
{
    max-width : calc(100% / 4 );
    max-width : -moz-calc(100% / 4 );
    max-width : -webkit-calc(100% / 4 );
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: It works only for webkit browsers - am I right? So there needs to be some other fix for FireFox as well. Anyway it's another way to do it, so +1.

Comment: Fully agree - but you probably know that some people will just copy your answer without thinking - so now you helped them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with no changes to the HTML or JS.

```
#myDiv img{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
#myDiv img:nth-child(4n+1){
    clear:left;
}
```

nth-child(4n+1) means applying those rules (clear:left) to every fourth image, but starting at position 1.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `div`, and set it's `width` (in CSS) to suit 4 images in the row. They will stack automatically. Something like this:

```
<div style="width: 400px">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="http://media.au.timeout.com/contentFiles/image/syd-venues/theatre/sydney-opera-house-482x298.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Or just add 4 images per dynamically-created `<div>`.

Comment: Yeah... there are a lot of ways to achieve this goal.

Comment: Did you mean `<div style="width: 416px">` (more or less) ;) Or floating images.

Comment: If it doesnt work for you, then you probably have some default `margins` or `paddings` attached. Can you check? It works perfectly in my chrome without `float`. But yeah - `float` is another option as well :)

Comment: check my answer. A little more dynamism allowed.

Answer (score 0):

define a new block of div and inside it another 4 blocks of fixed width div's

```
<div class="image-container">
      <div style="width:100px" id="1"></div>
      <div style="width:100px" id="2"></div>
      <div style="width:100px" id="3"></div>
      <div style="width:100px" id="4"></div>
</div>
```

now append your images inside of each div, so regardless of the width of the image there will be only 4 images per row

Comment: this code MIGHT break when the images are bigger than the div. Either that of the images will be truncated

Comment: yup images will be truncated to suite the width of the div
but it would be more practical than forcing all the images to have a constant width

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it through float property of css

```
<div style="/*total width of your 4 images placed side by side*/">
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
    <img style="float:left" src="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript.Add an image into N*4 matrix or Table.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(imgno)
{
    if(imgno%4==0)
    {
      document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    else
    {
      document.write("<td><img src=\"" + imgno + ".jpg\"/> </td>");
    }
}
document.write("<table><tr>");

var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=20;i++)
{
    myFunction(i);
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tables are really not the best solution to solve this answer. there are alot of better CSS solutions

Comment: All other solutions(css/html) are posted.So i thought of a table as no one mentioned it. Even the poster asked  Is there any way to do that in CSS or **js**, that's why posted a js solution.I think table are always the best solution for above question as it saves a lot of css,plus i guess table is always a cleaner solution. :)

Comment: true. I personally try and avoid a table cluttered site, but I guess it provides another option for the asker :)

Answer (score 0):

Only simple CSS will do that,

```
img{margin-bottom:5px;display:block; clear:both;}
```

Clear:both; will send the image to the new line, by clearing the float inheritance, and then it will automatically arranged below the previous element,

you can add other styles in that, but make sure you are not over-ridding it using `float` effect :)

Link to working fiddle :`http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/W3bsH/`

this will do your work in one line :)